# How to restrict special characters and letters for input field in angular 5

Tags: validation, input, pattern-matching, angular5

I'm trying to add an input restriction pattern in Angular 5 to an input field so users can only input the following (1234567890-.)

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" id="btn" (keyup.enter)="Submit(Car.value);" class="form-control" name="Car" #Car required placeholder="Car name" [value]="CarSearch" [pattern]="nameFormat"> </div>
```

And in the component:
i declare my pattern(wrong regex pattern):

```
nameFormat = "[a-zA-Z\s]+$";
```

then in constructor:

```
this.name = new FormControl("", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.nameFormat)]));
```

How can i achieve the correct regex pattern and restrict user input, the current solution is not working...thank you for suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using regex pattern,you can achieve this by using keycodes.

**In component.html**

```
 <input class="form-control" (keypress)="omit_number($event)" type="text">
```

**In component.ts**

```
omit_number(event) {
    var key;
    key = event.charCode;  //         key = event.keyCode;  (Both can be used)
    return ((key > 47 && key < 58) || key == 45 || key == 46);
}
```

**Explanation**

```
   (key > 47 && key < 58) // allows numbers from 1 to 0
    key == 45  // allows minus(-)
    key == 46 //allows Period(.)
```

Comment: Thank you, what about the dot (.) character?

Comment: in my case  i have  restrict only special character not letter can you tell me how to do for that?